# Show that one integral equals another using substitution

Tags: calculus

Show that 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$
Using substitution $t = 1/x$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I get how the limits change, but I can't figure out the rest

Comment: If $t=1/x$, then $x = 1/t$ and $dx  = \ldots  \, dt $ (can you fill in the dots)? Then replace $dx $ with this and $x$ with $1/t$ in the original integral, and simplify the algebra (and change the limits appropriately).

Comment: $dx = -t^2 dt$?

Comment: Not quite; remember, the dots should contain the derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$ (i.e. $\frac{dx}{dt}$, which is not equal to $-t^2$ if $x = 1/t$).

Comment: I think I got it now, the dots is $-x^2$. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} $$

$x=\frac{1}{t}$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-t^{-2}$

$dx=-t^{-2} \ dt $

Substitute back everything

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{-t^{-2} \ dt}{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}$$

Multiply denominator and numerator by $t^2$

We get $$- \int_1^\infty \frac{ \ dt}{t^2 +1}$$

As x goes to $\infty$ t becomes 0

As x goes to 1 t becomes 1

So the integral becomes $$ -\int_1^0 \frac{ \ dt}{t^2 +1}$$
 Now when we multiply an integral by - we interchange the limits

This becomes $$ \int_0^1 \frac{ \ dt}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The second integral is $\int_\infty^1\frac{-dx/x^2}{1+1/x^2}=\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$, where the $-$ sign is cancelled with an exchange of the integral's limits.